# Miracles that happened in the time of Jesus(ALAIHIS SALAM)

Tags: quran, prophet-isa, miracles

Asalamo Alaikum

Question 1:I am not able to understand a islamic concept.ALLAH states in the Quran that Hazrat Isa(Alaihis Salam) was given miracles.
I want to know,who performed the miracles?Did Isa(Alaihis Salam) just make dua and ALLAH himself perform the miracles or Jesus(Alaihis Salam) was performed them himself?
If soneone could explain this?

Answer (score 1):

**In the name of God, the Beneficent, the Merciful**

**All perfect praise be to God, the Lord of the worlds. I testify that there is none worthy of worship except God and that Muhammad 
￼
 is His slave and Messenger.**

---

**Your question:** Did Isa(Alaihis Salam) just make dua and ALLAH himself perform the miracles or Jesus(Alaihis Salam) was performed them himself?

**Answer:** No human including the Prophets could ever perform the miracles independently and without the Leave of God. The holy Quran in a general rule states that no miracle can ever take place without the Permission of God. As per of what God Said:

> ”And it was not given to any Messenger that he should bring a Sign (Miracle) except by the Leave of God.” **(40:78, 13:38)**

So, it is clear that every prophet and messenger made Du’a for a supernatural miracle and God granted permission to do so.

You asked what miracles did prophet Jesus performed? There are 6 miracles which Jesus performed:

1. **A Table Laden with Food**
2. **While Still in the Cradle**
   One of the miracles mentioned in the Quran, although not mentioned in the Bible, is that fact that Jesus, while still in the cradle, spoke out to protect his mother Mary from any accusations people may have placed on her due to having a child without a father.  When she was approached about this strange incident after her childbirth, Mary merely pointed to Jesus, and he miraculously spoke, just as God had promised her upon annunciation.

> “He shall speak to people while still in the cradle, and in manhood, and he shall be from the righteous." **(Quran 3:46)**

3. **And It Becomes a Bird**
   God mentions a miracle given to none other in the Quran but Jesus, one which is quite parallel to how God himself created Adam.  This miracle was one which none can argue its greatness.  God mentions in the Quran that Jesus says:
   "I create for you out of clay the likeness of a bird, then I breathe into it and it becomes a bird with God’s permission." (Quran 3:49)
4. **Healing the Blind and the Leper**
5. **The Resurrection of the Dead**
   "…and I bring to life the dead, by the permission of God." (Quran 3:49)
6. **The Provisions of Today and Tomorrow**
   Jesus was given the miracle of knowing what people had just eaten, as well as what they had in store for the coming days.  God says.

> ”I inform you too of what things you eat, and what you store up in your houses.  Surely in that is a sign for you, if you are believers." **(Quran 3:49)**

---

**Sources:**

1. [**al-islam.org**](https://www.al-islam.org/ancient-prophets-modern-world-true-story-jesus-shaykh-mansour-leghaei/miracles-prophet-jesus)
2. [**islamreligion.com**](https://www.islamreligion.com/articles/352/miracles-of-jesus/)